# Is there a proof of this that does not use idempotents?

Tags: modules, noncommutative-algebra

I am going to present a statement and a proof. The proof makes use of idempotents which makes it a little cumbersome.

> Is there a proof that does not use idempotents?
>   (using well-known theorems is OK even if their proofs do use idempotents)

Statement:

> Let $k=\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $G$ be a finite group. Consider the group ring $kG$. Let $I$ be the augmentation ideal of $kG$. Denote the Jacobson radical of $kG$ by $J=J(kG)$. Let $U$ be the indecomposable projective $kG$-module such that $U/UJ$ is isomorphic to the trivial $kG$-module $k$. Write $kG=U\oplus W$ ($W$ is the direct sum of the other indecomposable modules in the decomposition of $kG$).
>
> Then $I=UJ\oplus W$.

My proof:

> The augmentation map $\epsilon:kG\rightarrow k$ factors through $kG/J$ because $J\subset I$ because $kG/I$ is simple. Write $\epsilon=\epsilon'\circ\pi$ (that is, $\epsilon$ factors as $kG\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow}kG/J\overset{\epsilon'}{\longrightarrow}k$).
>   Let $U'=\ker\epsilon'$ and let $W'\subset kG/J$ be a direct complement of $U$' in $kG/J$. That is $kG/J=U'\oplus W'$. Write $U'=e_1kG/J$ and $W'=e_2kG/J$ with $e_1,e_2$ orthogonal idempotents. Since $J$ is a nil ideal (even nilpotent), we can lift $e_1,e_2$ to a pair of orthogonal idempotents $f_1,f_2\in kG$. Write $U=f_1kG$ and $W=f_2kG$. Then $kG=U\oplus W$.
>
> Now, it's easy but a little cumbersome to prove that $W \subset I$ and $U \cap I = UJ$. Thus $I=UJ\oplus W$.
>
> Finally, we have to our $U$ is the same $U$ as in the statement. It is enough to show that $U/UJ=k$. This is true because $UJ=U \cap J$ and thus  $U/UJ=U/(U\cap J)=(U+J)/J$. That last expression equals $k$, but to show it I need to use idempotents and again it's easy but a little cumbersome.

Comment: The idempotents are not too bad. You could also have used projective and injective properties of $U$ to handle lifting. However, there really seemed a lot of details to check, so I agree something easier would be nice. I gave a simple sort of “round peg does not go in square hole” argument that is often handy.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: What do you mean by "you could also have used projective and injective properties of $U$ to handle the lifting"?

Comment: Instead if lifting idempotents to get a direct sum decomposition $U \oplus W$, you could have let $U$ be the projective cover of $k$. Since $kG \to k$ is also surjective, we get that $U$ is a direct summand of $kG$ (both maps lift, but any map from $U$ to $U$ that leaves with $U \to k$ alone must be an isomorphism by definition of superfluous module).

Comment: The only “advantage” I can see is that this applies to (infinite dimensional over $k$) semiperfect rings, but so does your idempotent lifting, and probably so does my peg answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, $kG$ only has one part that can surject onto $k$; the rest is in the kernel.

In more detail: $kG$ is a direct sum of projective indecomposable modules $P_i$ each with a simple top factor $P_i/JP_i = S_i$ (with $d_i = \left|\{ j : S_i \cong S_j\}\right|$ the dimension of $S_i$). Since $k$ has dimension 1, there is only one such p.i.m. with top quotient $k$, and it is usually called $P_1$.

Consider the restriction of $\epsilon$ to each $P_i$. The kernel of the restriction certainly contains $JP_i$, but for $i > 1$ it must also contain the top factor too, since $S_i \not\cong S_1 = k$.

The kernel contains $JP_1 \oplus P_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus P_n$ but the quotient by that subgroup is already $k$, so the kernel of $\epsilon$ must be exactly $JP_1 \oplus P_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus P_n$. Here $U=P_1$ and $W=P_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus P_n$.

Comment: In the last paragraph, should "the kernel of $\pi$" be "the kernel of $\epsilon$"?

Comment: @user3533: yup, fixed.

Comment: In the third paragraph, do you mean that the kernel of $\epsilon$ must contain the top factor because otherwise the dimension of the kernel will be too small?

Comment: (Probably) No. I mean the image of $\epsilon$ restricted to $P_i$ is a submodule of the simple module $k$, so we have a homomorphism from $P_i/JP_i \cong S_i$ to $k=S_1$, but by Schur's lemma, such a homomorphism is 0 unless $S_1 \cong S_i$ (which it is not if $i>1$; part of Wedderburn structure theorem).

Comment: Despite our sloppy notation, $kG$ can actually have more than one simple module of dimension 1; we just call it $k$ when $G$ acts trivially. So $S_1$ doesn't have to be the only simple module of dimension 1, it is just the only $S_i$ isomorphic to $S_1$.